# Is there any way of getting additional information about unique constraint violations in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a client running Hibernate, is there a way of getting information regarding a unique constraint failure? The failure appears when committing the transaction, however no information is given about which class or entity is the offending party.

What i'm looking for is a way of determining if the item that is being inserted/updated, what class is it? and if possible, what was the originating class causing this insertion/update?

Is there a way of getting this information from the hibernate framework?

Or am I forced to analyze code and decide whether a cascade mapping is good or not?

Comment: Don't you see a SQLException?  I would assume that provides enough information to identify the cause.

Comment: We do get the name of the index that is violated. So we can lookup the index in the oracle db. However, i would like to omit this step if possible.